# MySQL Multi-source replication from 5.6 masters to 5.7 slave

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql5.6

In MySQL 5.7 multi-source replication is finally available.

Is it possible to use several MySQL servers running version 5.6 as multiple masters for a single MySQL slave running 5.7? Or do you have to upgrade all the masters to 5.7 to allow them to be a multi-source master?

Comment: yes, it's possible

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to replicate your MySQL 5.6 master to a MySQL 5.7 slave.